# How to dynamically change position of text displayed using css if text overflows the screen

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am designing angular app, I want to style the app such that it avoids showing text when it exceeds 128 characters. 
I want both the case to be handled, if it detects text is exceeding 128 characters then I want text to move left otherwise it remains in same position. How to achieve this?

This is css class that I tried altering this, but it didn't work for me.

```
#spandiv {
  background-color: #6B6664;
  padding: 5px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
}
```

**template.html**

```
 <mat-form-field >
     <input id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl">
  <p id="spandiv">{{customerName}}</p>  
     <mat-autocomplete panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn" style="width:750px;">
         <mat-option  *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async" [value] ="customer.AccountID + '('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
         {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
        </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If this works for you then you can do this in CSS

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  background: #dea827;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  width: min-content;
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>If less than or equal to 128 Chrachters:-</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <h4>If More than 128 Chrachters:-</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt tempore dignissimos sequi, sunt quasi necessitatibus illum ipsa sapiente.</p>
</div>
```